# Mysterious disappearance of an "upvote"?

Tags: support

How can it happen that I suddenly lose an upvote on this question [How can Kaluza-Klein particles be told apart from winding modes at the LHC?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19537/2751) (I had 3) together with 5 reputation points? Upon clicking "reputation" on my profile I see no downvotes or any other reason for this ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess would be that somebody upvoted you and then later reversed the upvote. Votes can be reversed either within 5 minutes (I think) of their original casting, or any time after the post is edited.

If you'd gotten a downvote you would have lost 2 rep, not 5, and it would show up on your profile.

Comment: Further, downvotes would show in [your reputation history](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2751/dilaton?tab=reputation), but the retraction of a vote would not. I think there is a discussion (or perhaps several) of this on the mother meta, but the team has never seen fit to do anything about it.

Comment: Thanks David and dmckee, this is a plausible explanation ...

Comment: Should a "retraction" of an upvote not be explained in the same fashion by a comment as a donwvote to clarify if after an edit the question is worse or if the original upvote was just a "slip of the mouse"? I mean in particular if the "retraction" takes place more than 24h after the last upvote and several hours after the last edit ...?

Comment: It would be polite to leave an explanation when you retract a vote, but it's certainly not required.

Comment: Then the question is, should the interface foster this? should a message appear when un-voting to prompt users to comment?

Comment: @episanty: that could be something to suggest on [metaSO]. I'm not sure how well it would be received; the community has rejected the idea of _requiring_ users to comment when downvoting many times, but given that there is a little popup notification reminding users to comment when they downvote, it might make sense to have the same thing when they retract an upvote.